# UIButton selector function weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift

In my application, i had a UIButton that works perfectly fine on

- XCode simulator (mostly with iOS 11.4 and iOS 14.5)
- physical device (iPhone 6: iOS 12.5, iPhone 7: iOS 14.5, iPhone 12: iOS 14.5)

My trouble is that some of my client's phone does not work as expected

- iPhone XR: iOS 14.5
- iPhone XS MAX: iOS 14.5
- iPhone 8 Plus: iOS 14.4

**Expected Behaviour** -
User clicked the button > call selector function > trigger callback > go to another view controller

**Client's Phone Behaviour** -
User clicked the button, and nothing happen. I'm pretty sure the app had captured the touch, because there's some shadow on button pressed.

Below is the sample codes i use

**MainViewController** : The purpose of this controller is to swap between different child view controller

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        return view
    }()

    private var currentContentVC: UIViewController

    init() {
        let childVC = ChildViewController()
        currentContentVC = childVC
        childVC.delegate = self
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        view.addSubview(containerView);
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        currentContentVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        addChild(currentContentVC)
        containerView.addSubview(currentContentVC.view)
    }
}

extension MainViewController: ChildViewControllerCallBack {
    func btnPressed() {
        let oldVC = currentContentVC
        let newVC = OtherChildViewController()
        newVC.delegate = self
        newVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        currentContentVC = newVC
        switchChildController(from: oldVC, to: currentContentVC, options: options)
    }
}
```

**ChildViewController** : Controller that consist of the troubled button

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerCallBack?

    private let mainV: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()

    private let detailV: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()

    private let myBtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "btn_gold_square")
        let imageRatio = (buttonImage?.size.width)! / (buttonImage?.size.height)!
        button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = Font.dynamicXSmallFont
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(Colors.black, for: .normal)
        let imageWidth = (SharedData.shared().dialogWidth + (SharedData.shared().dialogWidth * 0.1)) * 0.25
        let imageHeight = imageWidth / imageRatio
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageWidth).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imageHeight).isActive = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    protocol hildViewControllerCallBack: class {
        func btnPressed()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        view.addSubview(mainV);
        mainV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        [detailV, myBtn].forEach { mainV.addSubview(0) }
        detailV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        detailV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        detailV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        detailV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        detailV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        myBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailV.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        myBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainV.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    @objc private func btnPressed(){
        delegate?.btnPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this line ```currentContentVC.didMove(toParent: self)``` after addChild ```addChild(currentContentVC)``` in MainViewController class

Comment: Do you see any warning about constraints in console log? I have faced an issue about the constraints and it make some function does not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, the problematic line is this

```
private let myBtn: UIButton = {
```

All I have to do is change it to

```
lazy var myBtn: UIButton = {
```

If you wondering what and how does it work, for the long version, please refer to this [article](https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/lazy-var-in-ios-swift-96c75cb8a13a).

The short version:
A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.